# Why student registration id showing instead of student name in odoo

Tags: odoo

when i enter student's information then student id showing than student name.

here is url showin within form view.

Students/student.registration,2

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't have used/declared *name* field in *student.registration* object/class.

If you don't want to use/declare *name* field then you can use *_rec_name* for proper value display.

For example.

```
_rec_name = 'field_name'
```

It will show value of given field.

Or you can override the name_get method

Comment: Yeah ! its working now. I am new in odoo development so facing many problems. Thanks Bro